# Reduce image size while saving UIImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, colors, reduce

I have image with only red and white color. In image processing, we can reduce image from 24 bit to 8 bit or something like that.

Is it possible to reduce image size? In my iPad application, I can save image as png or jpeg. But I want to reduce the size more. How should I write code?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into the method `UIImageJPEGRepresentation`? Once you have your `UIImage` you just need to do something like:

```
NSData* imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(myImage, 0.4); //0.4 is the compression rate.
[imgData writeToURL:myFileURL atomically:YES];
```